# ArcGIS Pro: merge small polygons with their larger enclosing polygons

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, merge, geoprocessing, area

Polygons with an area size below a certain threshold should be merged with their enclosing polygons within the same layer. The image shows several cases in one example: in case of a threshold of 700, the green polygon A should be merged with the enclosing orange polygon B, and the orange polygons C and D with the enclosing blue polygon E. This can be done with a Python script with sub-steps like checking the size of the polygons and whether a polygon is inside another polygon.

Is there an option to perform the same workflow using a set of specific `Geoprocessing` tools?

While selecting polygons below a certain threshold is trivial, merging enclosing and enclosed polygons for instant merge does not look trivial.

ArcGIS Pro Version 3.1.3

[image: Merge enveloping polygons]

Comment: Explore [this tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/polygon-neighbors.htm)?

Comment: There's a number of ways to tackle this. Since the islands are already holes in an existing polygon, you could remove the holes below a threshold size with just some ArcPy code.

Comment: This is another [tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/cartography/aggregate-polygons.htm) worth exploring.

Comment: Look at the Eliminate tool as well.